# Loading class IWebUI from ADAL library fails

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

We get this error at runtime in our C# application:

```
{"Could not load type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.IWebUI' from assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.1.846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.":"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.IWebUI"}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were missing the assembly ADAL required. If you were developing with Visual Studio, I suggest that you use the NuGet to manage the libraries.

For example, I created a console application which use ADAL to acquire the token from Azure AD. Then we can install the ADAL by right click the reference->Manage NuGet Packages and search/install the ADAL like figure below:

[image]

And below is the code I acquired the token successfully:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AccquireToken();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async void AccquireToken()
{
    string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
    string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
    string clientId = "ce1c938c-001c-4caf-b078-9092103e1d49";
    Uri redirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost");
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
    Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
}
```

And in this case, the type of **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.IWebUI** is in **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform** assembly which will be installed/referenced automatically when we used the NuGet to install the ADAL library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep. we had done all those steps prior to getting the error.

Comment: Since the library works well for me, are you able to upload a sample project to help us trouble shoot this issue? You can upload it via [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-sg/) and please remove the sensitive information before you uploading.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete this file:

[image]

Not sure where it came from. It was not referenced directly. Must have been a relic from a previous version or reference or something. But deleting it worked.